# Automatic page refresh once per day

Tags: php

I want to refresh the page automatically once per day. I tried the following code:

```html
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="86400">
```

and tried with some javascript code also.But nothing is working. So anybody guide me to do this.

Comment: Do you really believe that anybody will stay on your page for 24 hours waiting for a refresh to see if anything has changed?

Comment: `meta http-equiv="refresh"` is used if you want to refresh a page x seconds AFTER the page has been loaded. So if I visit your page at 6pm it won't refresh at 0am for everyone. It will refresh at 6pm the next day for me only.

Answer (score 0):

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="86400">` only starts counting after the page has been loaded in the browser. If the tab is closed, then the count will stop and will reset itself even if you visit the same site again.

You have to use [Cron Jobs](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800) to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am using windows 7 . Is it possible to use cron jobs for Windows OS???

Comment: @SaranPHP I am assuming you are running your scripts from localhost. If that's so, I highly recommend you to find a free hosting service like [000webhost](http://www.000webhost.com/) and upload your files there using FTP. You should be able to use cron jobs from there, not to mention having your site accessible online.